# Setting dates on Jquery Datepicker Using a Button

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, datepicker

I am trying to give users the option to set a date range with the jquery UI datepicker by clicking a button.

They click the #month-pass-button and the dates in the #pass-start-date and #pass-end-date fields are set accordingly.

This works correctly, but a new datepicker calendar is created at the bottom of the dom. I don't want this to happen.

How can I correct this? Thanks!

Here is the code I currently have:

```
$(function () {
    $("#pass-start-date").datepicker({
        beforeShowDay: disableSpecificDaysAndWeekends,
        dateFormat: "M dd, yy",
        minDate: 0,
        onSelect: function (date) {
            var minEndDate = $('#pass-start-date').datepicker('getDate');
            minEndDate.setDate(minEndDate.getDate() + 7);
            $('#pass-end-date').datepicker('setDate', minEndDate);
            $('#pass-end-date').datepicker('option', 'minDate', minEndDate);
        }
    });
    $('#pass-end-date').datepicker({
        beforeShowDay: disableSpecificDaysAndWeekends,
        dateFormat: "M dd, yy"
    });
});

$(function () {
    $("#month-pass-button").click(function () {
        event.preventDefault();
        $('#pass-start-date').datepicker("setDate", "+0");
        $('#pass-end-date').datepicker("setDate", "+30");
    });
});
```

Comment: looks fine - http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/rscnb7zn/1/

Comment: do you mean the `#ui-datepicker-div` element?

Comment: what is the problem with the way jQueryUI inserts the datepicker element? Really not clear what your issue is

Comment: Sorry, I was unclear. It is adding a second datepicker calendar (#ui-datepicker-div element) to the end of the dom when the user clicks on the #month-pass-button. Although that jsfiddle works fine, so maybe I am misdiagnosing the problem...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$(function () {
    $("#month-pass-button").click(function () {
        event.preventDefault();
        $('#pass-start-date').datepicker("setDate", "+0");
        $('#pass-end-date').datepicker("setDate", "+30");
        $( "#ui-datepicker-div" ).hide(); // This line removes the date picker
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks. This does hide the datepicker, but I'd like to still be able to select the datepicker from the two input fields after users click the #month-pass-button. This prevents that.